# jpa/hibernate @ManyToOne putting null error: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException:

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence, many-to-one

I have form where I have decision select field like `OrganizationalCell`: When I choose one option f.e: `OrganizationalCellUnit`, I have to atach another input with entity `OrganizationalCellUnit`, which is mandatory only in that configuration.

When I choose other value, this one isnt (`OrganizationalCellUnit`) mandatory anymore.

I have my entity that I am trying to persist:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
public OrganizationalCell organizationalCell;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@Nullable
public OutPatientClinic outPatientClinic;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@Nullable
public Workshop workshop;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
public OrganizationalCellUnit organizationalCellUnit = null;

/** The clinic. */
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
public models.Clinic clinic;

/** The unit. */
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
public models.Unit unit;
```

And I am getting an error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: models.MedicalIncident.organizationalCellUnit -> models.OrganizationalCellUnit
```

In db these fields allow nullabe value.

How to make this field not mandatory, and make hibernate put null value in db

---Update----
After updating  CascadeType to all on that Many to one relation I have this error:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [models.OrganizationalCellUnit] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='error.required', propertyPath=updateUser, rootBeanClass=class models.OrganizationalCellUnit, messageTemplate='error.required'}
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='error.required', propertyPath=name, rootBeanClass=class models.OrganizationalCellUnit, messageTemplate='error.required'}
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='error.required', propertyPath=creationUser, rootBeanClass=class models.OrganizationalCellUnit, messageTemplate='error.required'}
]]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [models.OrganizationalCellUnit] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='error.required', propertyPath=updateUser, rootBeanClass=class models.OrganizationalCellUnit, messageTemplate='error.required'}
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='error.required', propertyPath=name, rootBeanClass=class models.OrganizationalCellUnit, messageTemplate='error.required'}
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='error.required', propertyPath=creationUser, rootBeanClass=class models.OrganizationalCellUnit, messageTemplate='error.required'}
]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:159) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
```

--- Edit Added

```
public class OrganizationalCellUnit extends GenericDictionary<OrganizationalCellUnit> {}
```

---

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class GenericDictionary<T extends Generic<T>> extends Generic<T> {

    @Required
    public String name;
    @Required
    public boolean active = true;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean stat) {
        this.active = stat;
    }
    /**
     * Options.
     *
     * @return the map
     */
    public Map<String, String> getOptions() {
        return getOptions(getList());
    }
    public Map<String, String> getOptions(List<T> list) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> options = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        for (T e : list) {
            GenericDictionary<?> entity = (GenericDictionary<?>) e;
            if(entity.active==true) {
                options.put(e.id.toString(), entity.name);
            }
        }
        return options;
    }

    public void on() {
        this.active = true;
        update();       
    }

    public void off() {
        this.active = false;
        update();       
    }
    public abstract String getFieldDescription(String name);
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == null) return false;
        if (other == this) return true;
        if (!(other instanceof GenericDictionary))return false;
        GenericDictionary<?> otherMyClass = (GenericDictionary<?>) other;
        return name.equals(otherMyClass.name);
    }
```

---

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Generic<T extends Generic> {
    @Transient
    public Class<T> entityClass;
    Generic() {
        entityClass = ((Class) ((Class) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]));
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @Constraints.Required
    public User creationUser;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @Constraints.Required
    public User updateUser;
    @Constraints.Required
    public String creationDate = Index.getDate(null);
    @Constraints.Required
    public String updateDate = Index.getDate(null);

    public User getCreationUser() {return creationUser;}
    public void setCreationUser(User user) {this.creationUser = user;}
    public void setCreationUser() {this.creationUser = User.getCurrentUser();}
    public User getUpdateUser() {return updateUser;}
    public void setUpdateUser(User user) {this.updateUser = user;}
    public void setUpdateUser() {this.updateUser = User.getCurrentUser();}
    public String getCreationDate() {return creationDate;}
    public void setCreationDate(String creationDate) {this.creationDate = creationDate;}
    public String getUpdateDate() {return updateDate;}
    public void setUpdateDate(String updateDate) {this.updateDate = updateDate;}
    public T getBy(Long id) {
        return JPA.em().find(entityClass, id);
    }
    public List<T> getList() {
        return (List<T>) JPA.em().createQuery("FROM " + entityClass.getSimpleName()).getResultList();
    }

    public List<T> getByUser_id(Long id) {
        List<T> entities = new ArrayList<T>();
        TypedQuery<T> query = JPA.em().createQuery("SELECT r FROM " + entityClass.getSimpleName() + " r WHERE r.user.id != :user_id", entityClass).setParameter("user_id", id);
        try {
            entities = query.getResultList();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            entities = null;
        }
        return entities;
    }

    public List<T> getByParameterAndValue(String parameter, String value) {
        List<T> entities = new ArrayList<T>();
        String sqlString = "SELECT e FROM " + entityClass.getSimpleName() + " e WHERE e."+ parameter +" != :value";
        TypedQuery<T> query = JPA.em().createQuery(sqlString, entityClass).setParameter("value", value);
        try {
            entities = query.getResultList();
        } catch (NoResultException e1) {
            entities = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Index.toLog("error","Unsupported error in Generic model class in " + entityClass);
        }
        return entities;
    }



    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        Logger.warn(this.toString());
        setCreationDate(Index.getDate(null));
        preUpdate();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate() {
        Logger.debug(this.toString());
        setUpdateDate(Index.getDate(null));
    }
    public void toDataBase() {
        System.out.println("------------------Trying to persist------------------------");
        JPA.em().persist(this);
    }
    public void update() {
        JPA.em().merge(this);
    }
    public void delete() {
        JPA.em().remove(this);
    }

    /**
     *  A Generic toString method that can be used in any class.
     *  uses reflection to dynamically print java class field
     *  values one line at a time.
     *  requires the Apache Commons ToStringBuilder class. 
     */
    public String toString() {
      return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE);
    }
//  @Override
//  public int hashCode() {
//      return id.hashCode();
//  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and it turned out (at least in my case) that this was Play's fault - I can see you using Play as well.

```
ModelObject object = form.get()
```

Even if *organizationalCell* field is not passed from the form, Play actually creates a dummy model object (of type OrganizationalCellUnit in your case). So object.organizationalCell is not *null*. JPA then rightfully shouts if you try to call

```
object.save()
```

What makes this incredibly difficult to spot is, that

```
object.organizationalCell.toString()
```

will actually write out "null".

The solution:

```
ModelObject object = form.get();
if(object.organizationalCell.id == null) object.organizationalCell = null;

object.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
public OrganizationalCellUnit organizationalCellUnit = null;
```

Use this

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public OrganizationalCellUnit organizationalCellUnit;
```

Comment: Ok. It work that I dont have that error anymore. Now is problem with validation: `play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [models.OrganizationalCellUnit] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]

` I've updated post with new stacktrace

Comment: Could you  post OrganizationalCellUnit.java code, please ?

Comment: It is quite complicated. It extends generics. Done